# KVO working once in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, key-value-observing

I'm trying to use KVO in Swift, but the method "observeValueForKeyPath" is called once.

[Here's a GIST of my code](https://gist.github.com/nicolas-besnard/53eeb9aeded700c28029)

I tried to use `NSNumber` instead of `Int`, add all options to `addObserver`, but the method is still call once when my view load.

Any idea ?

EDIT: It seems like I found a temporary solution using:

```
var lifes: Int {
    willSet {
        willChangeValueForKey("lifes")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

KVO requires dynamic dispatch, so the `dynamic` modifier needs to be added to the property:

`dynamic var lifes = 0`

Comment: +1 I love this. I looked around for documentation on this, but couldn't find it. Do you have a reference?

Comment: There is documentation for this that explicitly mentions KVO and the `dynamic` modifier in the Xcode 6 beta 5 release notes under the **Dynamic declaration modifier** section.

Comment: Thanks! I also just found very clear demonstration of this in the _Key-Value Observing_ section of [Adopting Cocoa Design Patterns](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-XID_5) chapter of the _Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C_ guide.