# swift - new Key-Value Observing (KVO) called only for .initial and not .new

Tags: swift

I'm trying to figure out the new KeyValueObserving (KVO) api. I dont know what I'm doing wrong because I'm getting `initial` observing ok but not `new` or `old`. This is what I'm doing:

```
import Foundation

class Foo: NSObject {
    @objc var bar = 0
}

let foo = Foo()
let observer = foo.observe(\.bar, options: [.initial, .new, .old]) {(o, change) in
    print("old: \(change.oldValue) - new: \(change.newValue) ")
}
foo.bar = foo.bar + 1
observer.invalidate()
```

Output I'm getting is:

```
old: nil - new: Optional(0)
```

But I should be getting:

```
old: nil - new: Optional(0) 
old: Optional(0) - new: Optional(1)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25208362/kvo-working-once-in-swift.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As documented [in *Using Key-Value Observing in Swift*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/using-key-value-observing-in-swift) you need to add `dynamic` keyword to your variable declaration.

Comment: thanks!!! maybe you can help me with this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47210513/swift-kvo-change-newvalue-and-change-oldvalue-are-nil

Comment: I think it will already work with `dynamic`. If it doesn’t, please post the entire sample.