# swift - KVO - change.newValue and change.oldValue are nil

Tags: swift

I'm using the new KeyValue Observing. I'm getting a call to my observer when the variable changes, but the `change` struct comes with `newValue` and `oldValue` both as `nil`, so it never gets to the `//do something` part:

```
let observer = foo.observe(\.bar, options: [.new, .old]) { obj, change in
   if change.kind == .setting && change.oldValue != change.newValue {
       // do something
   }
}
```

It used to work perfectly with the old way of doing KVO.

I made that code more simple as an example, here is a debugging of my actual code. You can see that the `m` object has the `status` var has been set to `PREPARING` but both `change.oldValue` and `change.newValue` are nil:

[image]

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: @MartinR I'm not being able to reproduce the issue in a minimal example but I posted a screenshot showing the variable values.

Comment: If you are observing enum (and it seems like you are), this might be cause of it:
https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5872

Comment: just cross-referencing a related question here on SO, still unanswered as of today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51737607/kvo-on-avqueueplayer-timecontrolstatus-always-gives-nil-values

Comment: @MartinMassera do you found the reason? I got same issue。 I observing UILabel's textAligment。

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a Swift bug which has been reported as https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5872. A pull request which addresses this issue is being discussed on https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/20757 but is not yet merged as of March 2022.