# KVO on AVQueuePlayer.timeControlStatus always gives nil values

Tags: ios, swift

I am using KVO to monitor `AVQueuePlayer.timeControlStatus`:

```
timeControlStatusObservation = avPlayer.observe(
    \AVQueuePlayer.timeControlStatus,
    options: [.old, .new],
    changeHandler: {
        [weak self] (player, change) in
        print("timeControlState: \(change.oldValue), \(change.newValue), \(self?.avPlayer.timeControlStatus)")
    })
```

`change.oldValue` and `change.newValue` are always nil, but `avPlayer.timeControlStatus` does have correct value. I got the follow log:

```
timeControlState: nil, nil, Optional(playing) 
timeControlState: nil, nil, Optional(paused)
```

Why KVO gives nil value? Is it a bug of the library?

Comment: just to add that, as of today, we're experiencing the same issue. BTW, have you got any news on this? Thanks

Comment: Also, here's a related question on SO, still unanswered as of today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47210513/swift-kvo-change-newvalue-and-change-oldvalue-are-nil

Comment: @superjos I haven't got any news yet, so I am not observing this property anymore.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [swift - KVO - change.newValue and change.oldValue are nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47210513/swift-kvo-change-newvalue-and-change-oldvalue-are-nil)